# Need a better description for [Support] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Can we make a better tag wiki for [Support]?

The current text is very unclear:

[image]

> Better Super User through use and working out why things are or how to better your experience here.

Proposal based on the SO tag and comment suggestion from [Journeyman Geek](https://meta.superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek):

> A request for assistance from community, moderators, or staff with one of the site's features.

---

**Update**: I have updated the 'Usage guidance' for the tag with the above suggestion. Since I don't have tag edit privilege yet it will go through the approval process.

Comment: And "things that scratch your head and poise to pose." in the body!

Comment: I would love to support you with a better description, but I suspect that [tag:helldesk] will not be accepted.

Comment: How does "Issues that may need input from the community, moderators or staff on improving how things are on SU" sound?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I presume you will spell out Superuser, always best (IMO), not to use shorthand when possible.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: the suggestion in your comment above reads well, but misses the meaning.  Support isn't necessarily about improving the site.  It's more likely to be about how to use what's here.